# Future Perfect Tense

Tags: grammar

I have 2 questions in the Future Perfect Tense. Is this question grammatically correct?

1- Will I have not cleaned the house?

I know we can ask this question like that: "Won't I have cleaned the house?". But I want to learn to ask this question without abbreviation.

How can I use "already" in Future Perfect Tense? Is that grammatically correct?

2- I am going to already have cleaned.

Comment: General advice on complex verb tenses:  "Don't"  Spend more time learning vocabulary and less time on obscure tenses and you will be a better speaker.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Social Network! It's best to ask one question at a time, but this is two separate questions. Also, the second one is not well formed enough for us to give you help. Your first question is, "Is a contraction required in this sentence?" Great question. Your second question is too broad. Are you asking if it's ever correct to use "already"? What about the second example are you unsure about? What sources have you checked already?

Answer (score 1):

1. You're close.  A better way to say this would be, "Will I not have cleaned the house?". This holds more closely to the same order as "Won't I have..."
   I cannot find any specific rule which makes this more correct.

   However, as a rule of thumb, in the conditional or any future tense, placing "not" before the verb "to have" in cases like this one is more likely to be well understood.
2. This sentence is not future perfect. It has become present continuous. Future perfect uses "will".  Instead, use "I will already have cleaned".  This sentence is correct and clear.

Comment: This answer seems good to me, iceburger. I don't know why it was down-voted. Perhaps whoever did it might explain.